# How to use WMI on Powershell to read IIS settings?

Tags: powershell, iis, wmi

I'm a begginer at wmi, powershell, IIS, and English.

Usually, I use get-wmiobject as follow SampleCode on powershell.
Target: WindowsServer 2012, IIS8
Powershell Run Client: Windows7ProSP1x64, Powershell v5, .NET 4.6.1

```
Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from Win32_QuickFixEngineering" `
  -Namespace root/cimv2 -ComputerName $hostname -Credential $cred
```

But in case of IIS, I don't know how to use that commandlet.

Is anything namespace collect? How search ClassName can be used for IIS on powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont necessary have to use WMI (i dont think it makes sense with IIS, but dont quote me on that). You can use `webadministration` module:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
Get-ChildItem –Path IIS:\AppPools
New-Item –Path IIS:\AppPools\MyAppPool
Get-ItemProperty IIS:\AppPools\MyAppPool | select *
Set-ItemProperty -Path IIS:\AppPools\MyAppPool -Name managedRuntimeVersion -Value 'v4.0'
Remove-WebAppPool -Name MyAppPool
```

Or you can use various cmdlets from the module to manage IIS

Comment: Thank you for your answer and editing my question, 4c74356b41.

Comment: did this answer help you? if yes you should consider upvoting\accepting this answer.

Comment: YES, your answer is helpful. I clicked on the check mark.